# Looping through materials and meshes (and animations) in a gltf file and importing into three js

Tags: reactjs, 3d, gltf, react-three-fiber, threejs-editor

I'm sure this has probably been asked before, but I'm fairly new to threejs (and React Fiber), so part of my problem here is not really knowing how to phrase what I need..

I know what I want to do must be possible, because it is possible to drag and drop any gltf file here: https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ and see it rendered correctly.

So, what I want to do, is create a loop which will traverse all parts (nodes?) of a gltf model with/without animations ([such as this one](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/final-sink-time-tech-503431223be34a5e8eba799b6ffb7a62)) and output it as part of a webpage.

Currently, I find myself tediously trying to add a `<mesh>` for each and every part of a model, and I know there must be an easier way.

I have found the [source-code for the viewer](https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-gltf-viewer/blob/main/src/viewer.js) here, but as mentioned, I'm still quite new to this library, so any help (or link to a similar question), would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using [GLTFLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader)?  There are additional samples in [gltf-test](https://github.com/cx20/gltf-test/blob/master/examples/threejs/index.js) and [gltf-vscode](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/gltf-vscode/blob/master/pages/threeView.js).

Comment: If you're using React Fiber, gltfjsx (https://github.com/pmndrs/gltfjsx) is probably what you want. It can automatically generate the JSX syntax for your glTF / GLB files.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy I just spotted that it is your gltf-viewer I referenced, it is very impressive (honoured to have you responding)! Are you using the gltfjsx binary to generate the correct syntax at runtime? I can probably use gltfjsx to generate the code and commit it to version control in my instance

Comment: Thanks @timhc22! :) Usually gltfjsx is not used at runtime for unknown models – you'd generate the JSX offline for a known model, paste that JSX into a React component's markup, commit it, and then you have a much more flexible way to work with the scene graph through React's component APIs. For example, to attach a ref to one part of the scene and animate that.